# Custom post type meta not showing `add_meta_box`

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Not sure what've I've done wrong, probably something really silly like I've missed an attribute or something.

Right I'm trying to build a feature on a theme that displays on the homepage. That bit I can do just fine. What I want to do is make this a little easier for the user. So they click image slider on the left hand side, add a title, add a description and! An image from the media library.

So far, to simplify my idea, I just want to add a custom meta field, as far as I understand, so the user can add an image address.

My problem is this meta box is not displaying in the admin panel and I'm not sure why? I've been reading and follow serval tutorials etc. Just can't seem to get it to display? Can anybody see anything wrong?

Here's what I've built

```
function post_support(){
    add_theme_support('post-formats',array('aside','Image Slider'));
}
/**
*       create slider, adding post register
*/
function slider_create_slider(){
    register_post_type('Image Slider',
    array('labels'=>
        array('name'=>__('Image slider'),
        'singular_name'=>__('Image slider'),
        'add_new'=>__('Add New slider object'),
        'edit_item'=>__('Edit Slide object'),
        'new_item'=>__('Add New Slide object'),
        'view_item'=>__('View slide object'),
        'search_items'=>__('Search Slide Objects'),
        'not_found'=>__('No Slide objects found'),
        'not_found_in_trash'=>__('No slide Objects found in the bin.')),
    'public'=>true,
    'show_ui'=>true,
    'capibility_type'=>'post','hierarchical'=>false,'rewrite'=>true,'menu_position'=>20,'supports'=>array('title','editor','thumbnail')));
}
/**
*       adding slider's meta boxes
*/
function slider_add_meta_boxes($post){
    //Only need to add image meta
    add_meta_box('ImageSliderMeta',__('image'),'slider_image_meta_box',__('image'),'side','default');
}
function slider_image_meta_box(){
    $image=get_post_meta($post->ID,'ImageSliderMeta',true);
    //only testing atm
    ?>
    <label>Image (url)</label><input name="ImageSliderMeta" value="<?echo$image;?>"/>
    ?>
}
function save_image_meta_box(){
    global$post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID,'ImageSliderMeta',$_POST['ImageSliderMeta']);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','post_support');
add_action('init','slider_create_slider');
add_action('add_meta_boxes','slider_add_meta_boxes');
add_action('save_post','save_image_meta_box');
```

Is it because I've structured my `add_action`'s incorrectly?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: There isn't one. Just doesn't display my custom meta field, never done it before. Just doesn't make sense to me? :S @Sildoreth

Comment: Could you please add this information to the question?  (1) what are you trying to achieve? (2) in what way is it not working?

Comment: @Sildoreth Sorry I'm well asleep today, Ok I'll edit, check back in 5

Comment: Your custom post type `Image slider` contains spaces and capital letters, [when it should'nt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters)

Comment: @MichaelDoye Ok I changed it :) still doesn't work :(

Comment: Just to be sure, have you clicked on the "Custom Fields" checkbox from the "Screen Options" tab at the top right of the screen?

Comment: @dojs yea, it just says slugs. So my code is right then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Your add_meta_box function is not passing the correct arguments.

Argument #4, $screen is the post types you want to show the meta boxes for. Use the following;

```
function slider_create_slider(){
   register_post_type('imageslider'
   ...
}

function slider_add_meta_boxes($post)
{
  add_meta_box('ImageSliderMeta',__('image'),'slider_image_meta_box', 'imageslider');
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: But what about custom meta fields? I only want the image meta_box rather than serval. Is that possible. Did work though :) thanks

Comment: What do you mean, what kind of field are you missing? Is your label showing (`<label>Image (url)</label><input name="ImageSliderMeta" value="<?echo$image;?>"/>`)?

Comment: Ohhh thank you! This makes a bit of sense.  I'll try it when I get home :)

Comment: Success!! Thank you so much! knew it would be something seriously simple!!

Answer (score 0):

I did it a few times. First, you must create the post type. In your plugin file, you must `require` the files, that define your custom post types and meta boxes. In your meta box file, you mostly generate a HTML code of the form element and add a function, that updates the post meta. I will give you an example (options_myplugin.php, required in the main file):

```
function myplugin_staff_meta_box_add() {
    add_meta_box('myplugin-staff-edit', 'Staff Social Meta Box', 'myplugin_meta_box_staff_cb', 'staffs', 'normal', 'high');
}

function myplugin_meta_box_staff_cb($post) {
    $position = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'position', true);
    $facebook = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'facebook', true);
    $twitter = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'twitter', true);
    $gplus = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gplus', true);
    $linkedin = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'linkedin', true);
    wp_nonce_field('staff_meta_box_nonce', 'staff_meta_box_nonce');

    ?>

    <p class="myplugin_option_box">
        <label for="position" class="myplugin-desc"><?php _e('Position', 'myplugin-nictitate-toolkit'); ?>:</label>
        <input id="position" type="text" name="position" 
            class="myplugin-option-input" value="<?php echo $position; ?>">
        <span>Ex: Project Manager</span>
    </p> 

    <p class="myplugin_option_box">
        <label for="facebook" class="myplugin-desc"><?php _e('Facebook', 'myplugin-nictitate-toolkit'); ?>:</label>
        <input id="facebook" type="text" name="facebook" 
            class="myplugin-option-input" value="<?php echo $facebook; ?>">
        <span>Ex: http://facebook.com/myplugintheme</span>
    </p>  

    <p class="myplugin_option_box">
        <label for="twitter" class="myplugin-desc"><?php _e('Twitter', 'myplugin-nictitate-toolkit'); ?>:</label>
        <input id="twitter" type="text" name="twitter" 
            class="myplugin-option-input" value="<?php echo $twitter; ?>">
        <span>Ex: http://twitter.com/myplugintheme</span>
    </p>

    <p class="myplugin_option_box">
        <label for="gplus" class="myplugin-desc"><?php _e('Google Plus', 'myplugin-nictitate-toolkit'); ?>:</label>
        <input id="gplus" type="text" name="gplus" 
            class="myplugin-option-input" value="<?php echo $gplus; ?>">
        <span>Ex: http://plus.google.com/myplugintheme</span>
    </p>
    <p class="myplugin_option_box">
        <label for="linkedin" class="myplugin-desc"><?php _e('LinkedIn', 'myplugin-nictiate-toolkit'); ?></label>
        <input id="linkedin" type="text" name="linkedin" class="myplugin-option-input" value="<?php echo $linkedin; ?>"/>
        <span>Ex: http://linkedin.com/myplugintheme</span>
    </p>
    <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'myplugin_save_staff_data');

function myplugin_save_staff_data($post_id) {

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;
    if (!isset($_POST['staff_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['staff_meta_box_nonce'], 'staff_meta_box_nonce'))
        return;
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post'))
        $allowed = array(
            'a' => array(
                'href' => array()
            )
        );

    if (isset($_POST['position']))
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'position', wp_kses($_POST['position'], $allowed));
    if (isset($_POST['facebook']))
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'facebook', wp_kses($_POST['facebook'], $allowed));
    if (isset($_POST['twitter']))
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'twitter', wp_kses($_POST['twitter'], $allowed));
    if (isset($_POST['gplus']))
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'gplus', wp_kses($_POST['gplus'], $allowed));
    if (isset($_POST['linkedin']))
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'linkedin', wp_kses($_POST['linkedin'], $allowed));
}
```

From now you will be able to display the meta values via `get_post_meta`.

Comment: I thought that, but my problem is but the field isn't showing up at all!

Comment: @sourRaspberri did you use `require 'thefilewhere_metaboxis_stored.php'` in the main plugin file? You know, the one, that has the same name as the plugin and is stored in the root folder of the plugin, like this: `require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'posttype/staff.php'; require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'posttype/options_staff.php';`.

Comment: erm no? I wasn't build a plugin as such, it's built into the theme but it's similar to a plugin. What's the file that I have to include? If I have to include one?

Comment: Am I looking into the wrong thing? I want a field like the title field?

Comment: Well, I haven't really worked with custom post types from template, only from plugins. Templates mostly define layouts and styles. If your custom post type exists, then just try to move the code, where you generate the meta box into a separate plugin. If you put the whole code into the main plugin file, you won't need the `require` calls, but I like my stuff to be ordered. Just start with copying the whole code I gave to a module file, then enable that module, than figure out what the code does, then remove/modify the code by your taste.